# jQuery получение атрибута через attr

Tags: jquery, attr

Есть две кнопки, которыми вызываются модальные окна

```html
            <a class="btn-show-modal js-show-modal" href="#js-block-modal">modal window</a>

<a class="btn-show-modal js-show-modal" href="#js-block-modal2">modal window 2</a>
```

дальше есть скрипт jQuery который вызывает эти окна при нажатии на кнопку с класом .js-show-modal скрипт получает атрибут #js-block-modal и вызывает окно, вопрос почему скрипт всегда получает атрибут первой кнопки когда я нажимаю на вторую

```js
   $('.js-show-modal').on('click', function(e){
       
        e.preventDefault();

        var currentModal = $('.js-show-modal').attr('href');
 
        $(currentModal + ', #js-overlay').fadeIn('fast');

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы берете не текущий элемент, по которому произошел клик, а первый элемент. Правильно работающий код:

```js
   $('.js-show-modal').on('click', function(e){           
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentModal = this.attr('href');     
        $(currentModal + ', #js-overlay').fadeIn('fast');
    });
```

Таким образом, вы получите через `this` текущий элемент.